# How do I interpret the meta information in a TIFF image?

Tags: image, matlab, tiff

The information of my image is as follows:
imfinfo('drosophila.tif')

ans =

```
                 Filename: 'drosophila.tif'
              FileModDate: '10-Nov-2009 18:52:42'
                 FileSize: 264768
                   Format: 'tif'
            FormatVersion: []
                    Width: 512
                   Height: 512
                 BitDepth: 8
                ColorType: 'grayscale'
          FormatSignature: [73 73 42 0]
                ByteOrder: 'little-endian'
           NewSubFileType: 0
            BitsPerSample: 8
              Compression: 'PackBits'
PhotometricInterpretation: 'BlackIsZero'
             StripOffsets: [32x1 double]
          SamplesPerPixel: 1
             RowsPerStrip: 16
          StripByteCounts: [32x1 double]
              XResolution: 72
              YResolution: 72
           ResolutionUnit: 'Inch'
                 Colormap: []
      PlanarConfiguration: 'Chunky'
                TileWidth: []
               TileLength: []
              TileOffsets: []
           TileByteCounts: []
              Orientation: 1
                FillOrder: 1
         GrayResponseUnit: 0.0100
           MaxSampleValue: 255
           MinSampleValue: 0
             Thresholding: 1
                   Offset: 264322
```

it shows bitdepth is 8.what does it mean?
how the filesize is calculated?
wat information is stored in format signature

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- This means that each of RGB colors is presented with 8 bits or 256 possible values for color.
- file size: ColorType: 'grayscale' - this means only 1 byte per pixel.
  512 height * 512 width =262144 bytes. 262144 bytes are compressed (Compression: 'PackBits') and some header with information is added at the beginning of the file. Totally 264768 bytes.

Comment: Header is part that contains the information you show here in some binary form. Refer to TIFF format specification for more info. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_Image_File_Format